# JS Firestore 'load more' pagination ignoring startAfter() and loading old data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pagination

I'm implementing a pagination where the user clicks a button to load more items.
I'm following the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors (paginate a query)

I'm passing in the last item id to the startAfter() function. This should make the next query return items that comes after the passed in item id.

What actually is happening, is that the previous items get loaded again.
So if the initial fetches looks like:

```
[
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
 2: {id: "3", stuff: ...}
]
```

the id 3 will get passed into startAfter(), and should load

```
[
 0: {id: "4", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "5", stuff: ...}
]
```

instead, it loads the initial items

```
[
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
]
```

So I end up displaying duplicate items when I press my 'load more' button.

initial fetch function:

```
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const obj = [];
      const firstFetch = await db
        .collection('recipes')
        .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
        .limit(3)
        .get();

      const snapshot = await firstFetch;
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        obj.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() });
      });

      const allRecipes = {
        userRecipes: obj,
      };
      setRecipes(allRecipes.userRecipes);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

The recipe variable logs:

```
[
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
 2: {id: "3", stuff: ...}
]
```

The button to load more items:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => showMore({ recipe: recipes[recipes.length - 1] })}
>
  Show More
</button>
```

Which calls the showMore function:

```
  const showMore = async ({ recipe }) => {
    const data = await db
      .collection('recipes')
      .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
      .startAfter(recipe)
      .limit(2)
      .get();

    const moreData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
    setRecipes([...recipes, ...moreData]);
  };
```

If I log the 'moreData' variable:

```
[
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
]
```

if I log the updated 'recipe' variable:

```
[
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
 2: {id: "3", stuff: ...}
 0: {id: "1", stuff: ...}
 1: {id: "2", stuff: ...}
]
```

So to me, it seems like it's ignoring the startAfter() function, and loading everything from the start instead.

Any pointers on what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
The actual data in the db looks like this:

```
{
about: "Non magnam quasi tempore."
createdAt: t {seconds: 1596741068, nanoseconds: 531000000}
description: "Ea quibusdam odit quasi corporis et nostrum."
imageUrl: "http://lorempixel.com/640/480/food"
ingredients: [{…}]
likes: []
title: "Ella"
userId: "U8n09jb0ZENwrZhDeYrJUSikcM12"
userSaves: ["uM7A4r5O6ENiX3qTL4tGhDXYA3Z2"]
username: "foobar"
}
```

the ID is the name of the document. The ID gets appended to the document in the initial fetch function.

**SOLUTION**:

Looking at Frank van Puffelen's answer, I had to provide the complete snapshot (which includes all info about the item), not only the array with items in it.

By creating a new hook with useState, I could store the state of the last snapshot in it:

```
const last = snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]
setLastDocSnap(last)
```

in my fetchMore() function, I was able to se the state in the startAfter() function:

```
const data = await db
  .collection('recipes')
  .orderBy('createdAt')
  .limit(limit)
  .startAfter(lastDocSnap)
  .get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce the problem. I've simplified your code to:

```
ref.orderBy('id')
  .limit(3)
  .get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    console.log("Initial query: "+querySnapshot.docs.length+" results");
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      console.log(doc.data().id);
    })
    var last = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];
    ref.orderBy('id')
      .startAfter(last)
      .limit(3)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        console.log("Second query: "+querySnapshot.docs.length+" results");
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          console.log(doc.data().id);
        })
      });
    });
```

And then run it on a collection with 5 documents, with `id` values `1` through `5`. It's output is:

> Initial query: 3 results

> 1

> 2

> 3

> Second query: 2 results

> 4

> 5

Which is as I'd expect it to be.

You can see the running code here: https://jsbin.com/qusijaw/edit?js,console

If my results don't help you get it working on your end, can you try to reproduce the problem in an environment like jsbin, so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: Is there a difference between passing the snapshot.docs and the snapshot.doc.data() to startAfter()? Will firestore be able to figure out where to load the next items from, by passing in doc.data? Or else i may have to do a big rewrite.

Comment: Firestore needs at the very least the `createdAt` value and the document ID of the document to start after. Since you're not passing the document ID, it doesn't have enough information to go on. Passing the `DocumentSnapshot` is the easiest way to ensure the database has what it needs.

Comment: Thanks. I believe this is it. Since this is Reactjs related, I created a new hook called lastDocSnap which I put the last snapshot inside. setLastDocSnap(snapshot.docs[snapshot.docs.length - 1]). I also passed the same in my fetchMore() function. It works well by sorting after 'createdAt'. Since I don't have an id field in my document (the document's name is the id) I probably need to do another write on creation, to put the document id inside the document as well. I guess sorting solely on createdAt can be dangerous if two items are created simultaneously. But it seems to work on createdAt.